# apache virtual host config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, virtualhost

I am using  apache  2.4.7  in ubuntu 14 .

my **mynewsites.conf** (/etc/apache2/sites-available) code is flows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin samplesite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user/Desktop/sampe_app/public

        <Directory "/home/user/Desktop/sampe_app/public">
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but samplesite.com url shows me the following errors

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

can any one tell me my i am getting this error ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

looks like a problem with the permissions of the folder change the /home/user/Desktop/sampe_app/public folder to be allowed to be viewed by others not just the user

chmod 777 folder path  < if your running ubuntu server (may need to grant sudo)

however i will warn you this is dangerous if you intending to host to the world probably best to only allow read and execute permissions (however this will mean users cant upload to this directory via your website) but in that case if you added further details to your requirements il try and adjust my answer accordingly

if you have a desktop manager installed can usually do it via file manager just navigating to that folder right click, then go to properties and permissions

Comment: after changing permission still same error any idea

Comment: All your directories leading up to the folder should have the "drwxr-xr-x"-permissions, if not you can change it using sudo chmod -R a+rx [your_directory]

Comment: failing that what does the Apache log say located at /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: oo one other thing after changing the .conf you did restart Apache server didnt you ? simple thing but easily overlooked on multiple occasions im speaking from personal experience

Comment: Hi in my app directory  permission is follows drwxr-sr-s can you tell me what is s denotes ?

Comment: 's' = The directory's setgid bit is set, and the execute bit is set.

is it working now , also are you just trying with a plain index.html

Comment: ya after change the permission form s to x .it's  start working thank you so much for your help